# Logs cut off in app insights before the end of an azure function process

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have an azure function which is logging to application insights which is set to store logs at information level.

All the initial logs are working fine, however it gets to a point and they stop. If I look at live metrics I can still see the logs being triggered but they don't appear in Application Insights.

Live metrics showing logs at 11:32

[image: Live Metics]

Application insights no logs after 11:31

[image: Application Insights]

The function itself runs for about 12 minutes but I don't know if this is a time thing.

Comment: It should be the delay in application insights. You can wait for a few more time and see if it's there.

Comment: Wasn't a delay, a few days have gone past and the logs for that session still end at the same place

Comment: Can you show some sample code, and the host.json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that the logs were being cut off due to app insights sampling feature (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?toc=%2fazure%2fazure-functions%2fdurable%2ftoc.json#configure-sampling) where app insights will start ignoring logs if the rate of logs goes over a threshold.